# PHP Use Google cse search for search queries

Tags: php, search

seems that this day google made ​​some changes, the script had to show results using search google but no longer works.
This code looking at "http://www.google.com/cse?as_q=youtube", and extracted the contents to get file contents, but now that path redirects to normal Google search "https://www.google.com/search?as_q=youtube" and don't shows results.

This is my code, maybe it can be modified and this will works, but I need your help, thank you very much in advance

this is the class: http://tny.cz/1c82c0b4

code php:

```
<?php
    $artist = str_replace("-", " ", $artist);

require("search.class.php");
$z          = new zentido();

function resultados($q, $p){
    global $z;
    $p          = ($p-1);
    $q          = $z->slug($q, '+');
    $contents   = $z->getUrlContains('http://www.google.com/cse?as_q='.$q.'&start='.$p.'0&lr=lang_es');
    $contents   = $z->comprimir($contents);

        preg_match_all('#<a class="l" href="(.*?)" onmousedown="(?:.*?)">(.*?)</a>#si',$contents, $lnk);
        preg_match_all('#<span class="s">(.*?)</span>#si', $contents, $info);

        $contents = array_merge($lnk, $info);
        /*
        4 -> info
        2 -> title
        1 -> url
        */
        for($i=0;$i<count($contents[0]);$i++){
            $_url = $contents[1][$i];

            if(strpos($_url,'argentinawarez.com') === false){
                echo "<article><div class='resultados_bus'><div class='resultados_bus_cont'><div class='bus'><span class='ico-stars'>&nbsp;</span><a target='_blank' rel='nofollow' href='".($_url)."'><h2>".strip_tags($contents[2][$i])."</h2></a></div><div class='bus_p'><p>";
                echo ($contents[4][$i])."</p></div></div><div class='resultados_bus_puntos'><p>".rand(10,100)."<br>Visitas</p></div></div></article>";
            }else{
                echo "<article><div class='resultados_bus'><div class='resultados_bus_cont'><div class='bus'><span class='ico-stars'>&nbsp;</span><a target='_blank' rel='nofollow' href='".($_url)."'><h2>".strip_tags($contents[2][$i])."</h2></a></div><div class='bus_p'><p>";
                echo ($contents[4][$i])."</p></div></div><div class='resultados_bus_puntos'><p>".rand(10,100)."<br>Visitas</p></div></div></article>";
            }
        }
    }

    resultados($_GET['artist'], 1);
    resultados($_GET['artist'], 2);

    ?>
```

Comment: What was http://www.google.com/cse?as_q=youtube supposed to do? How was it difference from a normal google search? Anyway you should use search API for that matter: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/

Comment: THE diference was: http://www.google.com/cse?as_q= (allows file get contents) https://www.google.com/webhp?as_q= (not allow file get contents) :S, I dont know how to use APi :S, can you help me T_T

Comment: I sent you a link to the documentation, I suggest you read it and follow the tutorials. Good luck.